# Throw an InvalidCastException or ArgumentException in structure's conversion method

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, argumentexception

I have some structures that are created from parsed JSON templates. So I have created a FromValue() method which converts the JSON string value to a structure to ensure only valid values are used and magic strings are not needed when editing the JSON object.

If an invalid value is provided, should I be throwing an InvalidCastException - as I am "casting" a string value to my structure type - or, an ArgumentException - as the argument is indeed invalid?

Here is one of my structures as an example:

```
Public Structure stContentJustify
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Left As stContentJustify
        Get
            Return New stContentJustify("left")
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Center As stContentJustify
        Get
            Return New stContentJustify("center")
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Right As stContentJustify
        Get
            Return New stContentJustify("right")
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Spaced As stContentJustify
        Get
            Return New stContentJustify("spaced")
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Shared Function FromValue(ByVal vsValue As String) As stContentJustify
        Select Case vsValue
            Case "left"
                Return Left
            Case "right"
                Return Right
            Case "center"
                Return Center
            Case "spaced"
                Return Spaced
            Case Else
                Throw New InvalidCastException(vsValue & " cannot be cast to a valid ContentJustify value.")
                'Throw New ArgumentException(vsValue & " is not a valid ContentJustify value.")
        End Select
    End Function

    Public ReadOnly Property Value As String

    Private Sub New(ByVal vsValue As String)
        Value = vsValue
    End Sub

End Structure
```

Comment: That is a bizarre type. Why are you not using an `Enum`? Don't work with JSON much myself but surely it's possible.

Comment: We have a web form designer written in javascript that is used directly in a browser window. The form styling is saved in a JSON string, including things like: {"contentJustify":"left"} etc. We occasionally need to manipulate the content of the forms that have been designed in code in our .net desktop software. So, I'm receiving strings and working in a similar way to creating a Color using Color.fromArgb().

Comment: OK, but that is not an answer to my question. Why can't a `contentJustify` field/property be of type `ContentJustify` that is an `Enum` with those four fields? In fact, there are already at least two `Enum` types that you could be using, including `TextAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment`. They just use different terms for `Spaced`, i.e. `Stretch` and `Justify`.

Comment: Yeah, this is an early design. I started rearranging the structure when you mentioned the Enum. It looks cleaner, so I will probably switch over to those. I would like to maintain the same terminology as the css properties, so I'll probably create the enum myself as you suggested. Your answer is helpful also. Thank you for you time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not casting anything there. You never need to throw an `InvalidCastException` yourself. It will be thrown if you actually perform a cast that is invalid. In your case, the issue is that the argument passed to the method is not valid and that is the very definition of an `ArgumentException`.